# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{s^b-c}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, laplace-transform, contour-integration, signal-processing

I am trying to find the inverse Laplace transform of $$F(s) = \frac{1}{(1+a\,s)^b-c}$$ where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive real numbers.

For $c=0$, we can use the following: $$\mathcal L^{-1}\left\{\frac1{s^b}\right\}=\frac{x^{b-1}}{\Gamma(b)}, \qquad for\quad b>0$$ Then we
have

$$\mathcal L^{-1}\left\{\frac1{(1+a s)^b}\right\}
=\frac1{a^b}\mathcal L^{-1}\left\{\frac1{(\frac1{a}+s)^b}\right\}
=\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{a}}}{a^b}\mathcal L^{-1}\left\{\frac1{s^b}\right\}
=\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{a}}}{a^b}\frac{x^{b-1}}{\Gamma(b)}.$$

Now, what do I do with $c\neq 0\,$?

This simplifies the question to:

> What is the inverse Laplace transform of $F(s)$ given by:
>   $$\frac{1}{s^b-c}?$$

Comment: Not sure where to start. If $b$ was a small integer, I would expand the denominator and try to separate fractions, but with a real $b$, I have no idea what to do. Mathematica is not helpful either.

Comment: Actually with real numbers this is too broad I think!

Comment: @MyGlasses, I don't think it is too broad, since $1/s^b$ has a known Laplace inverse (see my edit), and I am only subtracting a positive number from the denominator. I might be wrong, but if there is a solution, even in terms of special functions, it is a very useful addition to a Laplace inverse table.

Comment: So, I'm eager to know what's the answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduction to $c=1$ is just "time scaling":
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{s^b-1}\right\}=f(x)\implies\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{s^b-c}\right\}=c^{1/b-1}f(c^{1/b}x).$$
For the former, there's also a "series path": around $s=+\infty$,
$$\frac{1}{s^b-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}s^{-nb}\implies\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{s^b-1}\right\}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{nb-1}}{\Gamma(nb)}$$
as you know already, leading to the [Mittag-Leffler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_function).

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete solution, merely reducing the number of parameters in the integrand by one.

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}&\int_{\gamma - \mathrm{i}\infty}^{\gamma + \mathrm{i}\infty}
\frac{1}{s^b-c} \mathrm{e}^{st} \,\mathrm{d}s   \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}
\frac{1}{c} \int_{\gamma - \mathrm{i}\infty}^{\gamma + \mathrm{i}\infty} \frac{1}{(s^b)/c -1} \mathrm{e}^{st} \,\mathrm{d}s  \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}
\frac{1}{c} \int_{\gamma - \mathrm{i}\infty}^{\gamma + \mathrm{i}\infty} \frac{1}{(s/c^{1/b})^b -1} \mathrm{e}^{st} \,\mathrm{d}s  \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\frac{1}{c} \int_{\gamma - \mathrm{i}\infty}^{\gamma + \mathrm{i}\infty} \frac{1}{(c^{1/b}\hat{s}/c^{1/b})^b -1} \mathrm{e}^{c^{1/b}\hat{s}t} \,c^{1/b}\mathrm{d}\hat{s}  \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\frac{c^{1/b}}{c} \int_{\gamma - \mathrm{i}\infty}^{\gamma + \mathrm{i}\infty} \frac{1}{\hat{s}^b -1} \mathrm{e}^{\hat{s}\hat{t}} \,\mathrm{d}\hat{s}  \text{,}
\end{align*}
where $\hat{t} = c^{1/b} t$.
The singularities of $\frac{1}{\hat{s}^b -1}$ are on the unit circle.  (There's also a branch cut for almost all choices of $b$ which we may choose to run along the negative real axis).  So any $\gamma > 1$ suffices.

Comment: For $b$ integer, the contour can be closed along the big circle to the left and the residue theorem can be applied. The result essentially is (without constant factors): $$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} \sum_{k=0}^{b-1} {\rm e}^{t\,{\rm e}^{\frac{i  2\pi k}{b}}} \, .$$